# How to convert a mathematical expression into a tree/ .xml in R

Tags: r, xml, graph, tree, similarity

I have a list of mathematical expressions like the one below. My goal is to compare these expressions and cluster them based on the structure.

> (((53.0 / -98.0) * -2.0) + (-25.0 + 80.0))

I'm planning to use the [graphkernels package](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/doi/10.1093/bioinformatics/btx602/4209994) in R. graphkernels can compare two graphs and it generates a similarity matrix. But it uses the graph in xml format.

Are there any existing R packages which I can use to convert the expression into an .xml tree or normal tree which later I can convert to xml. I found the [data.tree package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html) in R but it doesn't seem to work for this case.  Any suggestion in terms of packages or a different approach please?

Answer (score 0):

[Phylogenic trees in R](http://www.phytools.org/eqg/Exercise_3.2/)

Maybe this would be somehow useful? Also Mathematica has got the function that you are looking for: 
[Mathematica Tree Form](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeForm.html)

Comment: Extremely sorry about the late reply. I have to try these as both are new to me. Thank you for the suggestions.